# Python extract values from nested dict

Tags: python, class, dictionary, nested

I am trying to extract some values from a nested dictionary, say x. I am interested to extract the value of item "status.availabilityState", which should return me only "available". How can I do this?

```
"status.availabilityState":{
                "description":"available"
```

More information:

print(type(x)), output

```
<class 'dict_values'>
```

print(x), output

```
dict_values([
    {
       "nestedStats":{
          "kind":"tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstats",
          "selfLink":"https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~xyz/stats?ver=15.1.3.1",
          "entries":{
             "actualPvaAccel":{
                "description":"none"
             },
             "clientside.bitsIn":{
                "value":1008535128
             },
             "clientside.bitsOut":{
                "value":3752299784
             },
             "clientside.curConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "clientside.evictedConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "clientside.maxConns":{
                "value":16
             },
             "clientside.pktsIn":{
                "value":200123
             },
             "clientside.pktsOut":{
                "value":157051
             },
             "clientside.slowKilled":{
                "value":0
             },
             "clientside.totConns":{
                "value":1714
             },
             "cmpEnableMode":{
                "description":"all-cpus"
             },
             "cmpEnabled":{
                "description":"enabled"
             },
             "csMaxConnDur":{
                "value":72054987
             },
             "csMeanConnDur":{
                "value":120811
             },
             "csMinConnDur":{
                "value":32
             },
             "destination":{
                "description":"1.1.1.1:443"
             },
             "ephemeral.bitsIn":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.bitsOut":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.curConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.evictedConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.maxConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.pktsIn":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.pktsOut":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.slowKilled":{
                "value":0
             },
             "ephemeral.totConns":{
                "value":0
             },
             "fiveMinAvgUsageRatio":{
                "value":0
             },
             "fiveSecAvgUsageRatio":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.msgIn":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.msgOut":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.reqIn":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.reqOut":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.respIn":{
                "value":0
             },
             "mr.respOut":{
                "value":0
             },
             "tmName":{
                "description":"/Common/xyz_Local_443"
             },
             "oneMinAvgUsageRatio":{
                "value":0
             },
             "status.availabilityState":{
                "description":"available"
             },
             "status.enabledState":{
                "description":"enabled"
             },
             "status.statusReason":{
                "description":"The virtual server is available"
             },
             "syncookieStatus":{
                "description":"not-activated"
             },
             "syncookie.accepts":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.hwAccepts":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.hwSyncookies":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.hwsyncookieInstance":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.rejects":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.swsyncookieInstance":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.syncacheCurr":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.syncacheOver":{
                "value":0
             },
             "syncookie.syncookies":{
                "value":0
             },
             "totRequests":{
                "value":21186
             }
          }
       }
    }
 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's common dictionaries have nested values. You need to specify the chain of keys when you want to access the value in a nested dictionary.

Per your example:

```
"status.availabilityState":{
            "description":"available"
}
```

If you wanted to print the value detailed in your question, you'd want to do something like...

```
print(x["nestedStats"]["entries"]["status.availabilityState"]["description"])
```

Considering X is a simple nested dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a prompt response. I am getting the following error when I tried your solution `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`. I must mention x in the above is values of dictionary as indicated in the output of type(x), which is `<class 'dict_values'>`.

Comment: I was able to extract the desired value after converting the dict value into a list. Thank you so much for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: @ashabc sorry for the delayed response, I am glad you were able to get it sorted out with the nudge in the direction. Take care!